# Console when debugging on device

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

If I debug my Cordova project on a device, I am not sure where the console.log() output goes. A ton of text scrolls past in the Visual Studio Output window, but I can't believe we are supposed to search through that lot to get the wanted lines (it continuously scrolls anyway). The debug output is filtered nicely in browser console, but I can't debug in browser unfortunately.

In the auto generated code the following comment is added:

- To debug code on page load in Ripple or on Android devices/emulators: launch your app, set breakpoints,  and then run "window.location.reload()" in the JavaScript Console.

Again, what console is this? Apologize if it is really obvious, but my Google searches has not revealed anything

Answer (score 3):

Thanks both of you. I have the JavaScript console now and it is doing exactly what I asked for. In case others may wonder you can not activate the JavaScript console under the view-menu as mentioned above. You have to start debugging and then select it  under the Debug->Windows menu. This option is hidden when editing code.

Comment: +1 Yes, the exact sequence of commands in Visual Studio 2015 is Debug --> Start Debugging. [Wait for app to load on device] then click Debug --> Windows --> JavaScript Console.

Answer (score 2):

You can view the console.log() output in JavaScript Console and you can use it to execute JavaScript too. JavaScript Console window should be visible when you launch the app under "Start with debugging".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a separate 'JavaScript Console' window that you should have when debugging on device or in Ripple, maybe try turning it on under the View menu if your not seeing it?

Comment: this won't work unless you have Debugging turned on. The exact sequence of commands in Visual Studio 2015 is Debug --> Start Debugging. [Wait for app to load on device] then click Debug --> Windows --> JavaScript Console.